# Raphael js - gettotalLength() and getBBox.width

Tags: javascript, path, raphael, bounding-box

Can anyone tell me, why the totalLength of a horizontal path from point (0,100) to (100,100) is 200 and the BBox-width is 100?

Here is the code:

```
var p  = paper.path('M0 100 L100 100Z')
console.log(p.getTotalLength(), p.getBBox().width)
// Result 200, 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is best illustrated when we try to draw a square path with one of the sides intentionally omitted from the path.

Lets say we want to draw a square of one user unit in size, with one of its sides not included in the path attribute(`d`). So we will get `r.path('M0 0L1 0L1 1L0 1Z')`; or `r.path(M0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1)`. Here we have not explicitly drawn the last side of the square.

We will expect that path's, getTotalLength to return 3, but it will return 4. This is because the pen has to close the path from the last point in path to the first point in the path (the job of `z`). Even if you don't specify `z` at the end of the path's `d` attribute, the pen will travel from its last point in the path to the first point of the path with white ink stroke. So the total path drawn is 3 side of the square with black ink and one side of the square with white ink, that's why it returns 4. The same applies for lines.